# Python - Is there a another way to run a python script from a python script besides os.system?

Tags: python, cloudera, os.system

Is there a another way to run a python script from within a python script besides os.system?  At the end of a python script I tried to run another python script but I am running into a permissions error.  This may just be due to my access, or maybe there is a better way to run this in the Cloudera Data Science Workbench where I dont run into a permission issue?

```
num_of_rows_parsed_url_df = len(parsed_url_df)
num_not_on_maj_one_mil = len(parsed_url_df[parsed_url_df.GlobalRank == 1000001])
print "Number of Rows: ",num_of_rows_parsed_url_df
Number of Rows:  34091
print "Number of Requests not on the Majestic Million: ", num_not_on_maj_one_mil
Number of Requests not on the Majestic Million:  17613

import os
os.system("Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py")
32256sh: 1: Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py: Permission denied
os.system("Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py 1")
32256sh: 1: Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: allow permission for Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py and script itself by chmod +x Proxy/Proxy_Analytics/AWS_API_Cost.py and do the same with your script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only is `os.system` not the only way, it's a particularly *bad* way. `os.system` is a security hazard and should be avoided almost 100% of the time.

What it sounds like you want is `subprocess.run`. If you want to run another Python script using the same interpreter that's running the current one, you can do:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.run([sys.executable, os.path.abspath('path/to/script.py')])
```

That said: are you sure you want to run the other script as a separate *process*? Most likely, the better solution would be to extract a reusable *library* of Python functions, and `import` that library into your various scripts.

Creating and packaging a collection of Python modules into a reusable library can be a non-trival task, because it moves you away from "a collection of unrelated scripts" and toward "a packaged programming product". If you have scripts that need to start sharing implementation details, then it probably behooves you to start thinking of the shared code as a library anyway.

Comment: [This](https://www.kevinlondon.com/2015/07/26/dangerous-python-functions.html) is a decent article about dangerous Python functions, of which `os.system()` is highlighted.

Comment: Indeed, `os.system` is just a Python wrapper around the C standard library `system` call, which is well known to be vulnerable. Read the "Caveats" section of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) for more information.

Comment: My goal is to schedule "script_1.py" in CDSW at a specific time which query's proxy data and assigns Alexa Million ranks to it and stores the new data.  At the end of  "script_1.py" I want to kick off "scirpt_2.py" which uses the data that was created in "script_1.py" and does other things with it.  @Daniel Pryden

Comment: I know nothing about CDSW, so I can't help you there. But I think my answer still stands.

Comment: @sectechguy: If you get an error about `run` not existing in the `subprocess` module, you are likely running an old version of Python. `run` was added to the `subprocess` module in 3.5. If you don't need the standard output of the other script, you should be able to replace `run` with `check_call` and get an equivalent effect.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info, it worked! @DanielPryden